# JLayeredPane z-order issue

Tags: java, swing, type-conversion, z-order, jlayeredpane

While using JLayeredPane to add Compnents in z-order, I noticed some issue:

```
JLayeredPane lp = getLayeredPane();

JButton top = new JButton(); ...
JButton middle = new JButton(); ...
JButton bottom = new JButton(); ...
```

Works bad:

```
lp.add(top,2);
lp.add(middle,1);
lp.add(bottom,3);
```

Works good:

```
lp.add(top,new Integer(2));
lp.add(middle,new Integer(1));
lp.add(bottom,new Integer(3));
```

Here you can see how it looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TwSJ.png

Why is literal constant not converted into Integer object, and it does not work properly?

Answer (score 3):

In essence because the class it inherits from (Container) has a function to add a Component at a given position in it's list of components ([`add(Component comp, int layer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add(java.awt.Component,%20int))), as well as a function to add a Component with any given argument (to be passed to the LayoutManager) ([`add(Component comp, Object constraint)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object))).

In order for the right function to be called (and JLayeredPane's LayoutManager to receive the constraint) the argumentmust be an Object `Integer` and not a primitive `int`.

Answer (score 3):

> Why is literal constant not converted into Integer object, and it does not work properly?

You need to look at the API for the `add(...)` method.

The `Container` class has a method that accepts an "int" as a parameter. This is used for layouts like the FlowLayout where you can insert a component at a specified position.

The `JLayeredPane` class has a method that accepts an "Integer" value to specify the layering of the component.

So you can't depend on autoboxing to convert the int to an Integer.